# what's wrong in std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double>>

Tags: c++, pointers, shared

I am under impressions that std::shared_ptr doesn't free memory when it gets out of scope. Below is my test code. Can you please suggest me what I am doing wrong.
I use gtest for testing. When I execute this test I can see that memory is constantly consumed. I use Microsoft VC++ 2013.

```
    void ProceedVector() {
    std::vector<double> * numbers = new std::vector<double>();
    for (int ind = 0; ind != 10000; ind++) {
        numbers->push_back(ind);
    }
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double>> numbersPtr = std::make_shared<std::vector<double>>(*numbers);
}

TEST_F(ManagerTypeConvertorTest, ProceedVector) {
    for (int ind = 0; ind != 50000; ind++) {
        ProceedVector();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 2):

Each call to `ProceedVector` does two dynamic allocations of `std::vector<double>` objects. One here:

```
std::vector<double> * numbers = new std::vector<double>();
```

And the other one here:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double>> numbersPtr = std::make_shared<std::vector<double>>(*numbers);
```

`make_shared` doesn't mean "assign this object to a `shared_ptr`." It means "allocate a new object from these parameters, and manage the newly allocated object using a `shared_ptr`."

Depending on what you want the code to achieve, either replace the `new` line with the `make_shared` one and don't use a raw pointer at all, or replace the `make_shared` line with this:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<double>> numbersPtr{numbers};
```

That will construct a `shared_ptr` which will manage the memory pointed to by `numbers`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped!

Answer (score 0):

You have *two* pointers to *two different* vectors:

- One which will be deleted (the shared pointer containing a copy of the contents from the first vector)
- And one which will *not* be deleted (the first vector you create with `new`).